# How can I pull data out of this string with PHP? Using RegEx?

Tags: php, regex, string, substring

Here is the string I have from a server:

> 70.90.184.9 Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/536.30.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.5 Safari/536.30.1

The data I need pulled out should be like this:

```
$ip = "70.90.184.9"
$os = "Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4"
```

Is there a RegEx to get the IP out easily in PHP? And what about the OS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the function [`get_browser()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) for this. It's a hidden treasure ;) Call:

```
$str = '70.90.184.9 Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/536.30.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.5 Safari/536.30.1';
var_dump(get_browser($str));
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of depending on browscap.ini. It relies on user updates to keep the database current. I'm more looking to do the parsing myself just for the single string as shown.

Comment: I could give you a regex especially for that string, but as @Sverri pointed out, user agents are unreliable at all..

Answer (score 2):

Use the [PHPBrowsCap](https://github.com/GaretJax/phpbrowscap) project. It is a stand-alone class that tries to get around the limitations of the `get_browser()` function.

Parsing user agent strings is notoriously difficult and unreliable. The aforementioned project is probably the best way of getting usable user agent information. That being said, please do not use user agent strings to put up "This website only supports browser X" messages -- people will hate you for it.

Comment: This sounds interesting. +1

Comment: "please do not use user agent strings to put up 'This website only supports X browser' messages" - This is not my intent, don't worry.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like this won't work for me either. With a user agent string of iPhone OS 6_1_4 the PHPBrowsCap project displays it as iOS version 6.1. I need the full 6.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern do the job for your example, but i am not sure that it will be the same for an another string:

```
^([\d.]++)[^(]++\(\S++\s([^)]++)
```

If you want a more general pattern, please update your post with some possible examples which can be useful to determine a more global syntaxe. However, regex alternatives as Sverri suggests is perhaps a good way.